# How to use ternary operator on nested object field to validate my typescript type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Am I doing something wrong here or is this by design?

I would like to be able to write something like this.

```js
type MyType = {
    greeting: string;
    value?: { valueType: string; value?: string };
};

function generate(name: string, input?: Partial<MyType['value']>): MyType {
    return {
        greeting: `Hello, ${name}`,
        value: input?.valueType ? input : undefined,
    };
}
```

As you can see I'm using a ternary operator to validate that my `input` object is valid, but TypeScript complains and gives an error:

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)

---

[TypeScript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsmAKpWBeGBvYMcwOYBOUUIAlgHZ4BcMAziARXgNza4BuAhgDYCuUAfhpZcomFz5Rk0GvUaVWYjj35C6DJotwBfVruDAAZr3IBjMgHty+KOSgFOIKAApynALZRZGygBoYFBC8IGoACpwEZDwAPAjSUADaAOQS-EkAugB8AJQ0cSiYBqJEILwE1iJK+EQkTDQABgASUNzcFv4AJBhuntr1vmxKqV4B5EEhAHTD8TACo+MwNCYAJlCGFFDLA6L62gZAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript narrowing worked as intended if you redefine your object properties. Working example :

Code :

```
type MyType = {
    greeting: string;
    value?: { valueType: string; value?: string };
};

function generate(name: string, input?: MyType['value']): MyType {
    return {
       greeting: `Hello, ${name}`,
       value: input?.valueType ?  {
            valueType: input.valueType,
            value: input.value
        } : undefined,
    };
}
```

@see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29827

Comment: This would change the semantics and not allow to pass `input` with a missing `valueType` property, while OP's code allows that. I'm just mentioning it in a comment - it's not really clear whether OP really needs to pass objects without `valueType` into the function or not.

Comment: I would also like to be able to call the function like this: `generate('Jógvan', { value: 'without a type' });`

Comment: I understand better what is your intent now. I edited my post with keeping the possibility to use an object like this :  `{ value: 'obj with no valueType' }`

Comment: What you provided is exactly what I wanted to avoid, but I see that is what is needed. But here's someone showing with 3 lines why what I want is not supported: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33205#issuecomment-527313227

Answer (score 1):

To understand what went wrong, first, let's inspect the type in return position. It's `value` property has the following type (as expected):

```ts
{ valueType: string; value?: string | undefined; } | undefined;
```

Let's also inspect what the `input?.valueType ? input : undefined` yields us:

```ts
Partial<{
    valueType: string;
    value?: string | undefined;
}> | undefined
```

And therein lies the problem: you told the compiler you expect `valueType` to be of type `string` but what you actually tried to assign to it is `string | undefined` (obviously because the `Partial` helper made the `valueType` property optional).

The `Partial<T> | undefined` is inferred since you also told the compiler that the `generate` function accepts `Partial<MyType['value']>` as the second parameter. Now, what can you do about it? Without changing the semantics, the only sound option is to make the `valueType` optional as well:

```ts
type MyType = {
    greeting: string;
    value?: {
        valueType?: string;
        value?: string;
    };
};

function generate(name: string, input?: Partial<MyType['value']>): MyType {
    const value = input?.valueType ? input : undefined;
    return { greeting: `Hello, ${name}`, value }; //OK
}
```

That's probably not what you are looking for. However, to achieve your goal, you need optional chaining to both act as a type guard and "map" the type you told the compiler is `Partial` to remove the modifiers. This is possible with a user-defined [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which may look like this:

```
const withType = (val: Partial<MyType["value"]>) : val is Exclude<MyType["value"], undefined> => !!val?.valueType;

function generate(name: string, input?: Partial<MyType['value']>): MyType {
  const value = withType(input) ? input : undefined;
  return { greeting: `Hello, ${name}`, value }; //OK
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/N4KABBYC4J4A4FMwFkYBV5ILxlJfYA5gE4IJQCWAdoQFxgDOUx1hA3OARAG4CGANgFcEAfnp4uBPkIQZEYxs1YdJUgcIVMWNFZIC+uiAZCcIAM0FUAxpQD2VIgioJivKAgAUVXgFsE9LVYAGjBqOEEoBQAFXmJKAQAeVDkEAG0AcmlhdIBdAD4ASnpkzFxTAit7JjAs7FCqcMiAOlqUsBF6xrB6SwATBDNqBF7DAlIoQWIHYCJSclZ6AAMACQR+flsQgBJgbz89RZDasGN8PRBzkAkIWEQUdFKca4ISMkoaAKUdcvxahWfVK1MJ9tOwfpI-iDlOCjKNjOVKlRqgB3ChQAAWbRwHmk9BicQoiRKiFSACJaqT8gVujUBKEGGAAKIADysQn6SQeJPJ6gQlJCfQGQ16eTAWFFAEIJdIRC1eSkOOULNY7A5CE4XG5PHt-IpQSEwhForF4vxOSkMrVcoVilykADIIjqsccKiMSkPIaoNSOl6aYLBs4RjCwONJtNZm8FmAVmsNttdr4EAcjryTnCLkA)